Horizontal Lisview.builder with elements together
I'm new to Flutter and I would like to create a ListView that looks like the uploaded image.
Is it created using a ListView.builder with Positioned children, or is there another approach? I'm a bit confused about this. I've tried something like the code below, but the elements in the ListView.builder are separated. Does anyone have any ideas or can offer some help?
Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            width: size.width*0.5,
            height:30,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: userUpdate.lastBoardgamesAdded!.length ,              
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                child: 
                        ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              child: FadeInImage(
                                          height: 25,
                                          width: 25,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          placeholder:  const AssetImage('assets/loaders/bottle-loader.gif'),
                                          image:  AssetImage('assets/images/boardgames/${userUpdate.lastBoardgamesAdded![index].imgUrl}'),
                                ),
                      ),
              );
                
              },),
    
          )

Expected results

You can try Stack instead of ListView. Hope it help!
    Stack(
      children: ['1', '2']
          .indexed
          .map(
            (e) => Positioned(
              left: e.$1 * 10,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Item ${e.$2}'),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );

